# sorting lists using sortBy

Tags: haskell

I am trying to sort my list of tuples based on the 4th element in each of the tuples.  The fourth element contains a string that is a person's name. I want to put tuples that contain the same name next to each other. An example of the lists of tuples before it is sorted is:

```
[("A",100,"Q",3,"Todd",2.0),
 ("B",203,"R",3,"Rachel",1.66),
 ("B",273,"F",1,"Mike",2.66),
 ("A",200,"P",1,"Rachel",0.0),
 ("A",549,"D",3,"Todd",2.0),
 ("B",220,"S",3,"Todd",4.0),
 ("B",101,"M",3,"Jon",3.33),
 ("A",999,"N",3,"Rachel",1.33)]
```

I want it too look like:

```
[("A",100,"Q",3,"Todd",2.0),
 ("A",549,"D",3,"Todd",2.0),
 ("B",220,"S",3,"Todd",4.0),
 ("B",203,"R",3,"Rachel",1.66),
 ("A",200,"P",1,"Rachel",0.0),
 ("A",999,"N",3,"Rachel",1.33),
 ("B",273,"F",1,"Mike",2.66),
 ("B",101,"M",3,"Jon",3.33)]
```

What I need is for all the tuples that contain Todd to be next to each other and so on for each name. The order the names show up doesn't matter, just that they are next to each other.

```
sortedList= show . sortBy byName . (map stringToTuple) . (map words) . lines
```

This is the line of code I am calling sort by in. I understand I need to make a function `byName` that will somehow figure out if the tuples share a common name.

Any help to steer me into the right direction for writing the `byName` method would be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Start with the type of `sortBy`:

```
> :t sortBy
sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
```

This means `byName` needs to have type `a -> a -> Ordering`. In this case, `a` is a tuple whose fifth element as type `String`; `byName` will ignore the other fields. So you'll need to define a function like

```
type MyType = (String, Int, String, Int, String, Double)
byName :: MyType -> MyType -> Ordering
byName (_, _, _, _, a, _) (_, _, _, _, b, _) = ...
```

I leave replacing the `...` with the correct expression as an exercise.

(Recall that `Ordering` is a type with three values, `LT`, `EQ`, and `GT`, where `byName a b == LT` if `a < b`, `byName a b == EQ` if `a == b`, and `byName a b == GT` if `a > b`. In your case, two tuples will compare as equal as long as they have the same name. It sounds like you don't actually  care whether `byName` returns `LT` or `GT` otherwise.)

Comment: The definition of MyType needs to be fixed (or removed) since the type variables (a,b ...) are not in scope.

Comment: Oops, thanks. I'll be conservative and just define it to match the tuples shown.

Comment: If I then wanted to group the tuples with similar names into one big tuple I would use groupBy. Is this the right direction to go?



computeGpas = show . groupBy groupName . sortBy byName . (map stringToTuple) . (map words) . lines



groupName :: MyType -> MyType -> Bool
groupName (_, _, _, _, a, _) (_, _, _, _, b, _) = True

Answer (score 4):

While you can figure something like this out for yourself, most of the desired capability is already available via `Data.Ord`. If `tuples` is your input list, you can just use:

```
sortBy (comparing name) tuples
```

where `name` is a utility function defines as:

```
name (_, _, _, _, n, _) = n
```

This is actually a parametrically polymorphic function, so you could also call it `fifth`, or something generic like that.

You can call the above expression and format the output to see that it does approximately what you want:

```
Prelude Data.Ord Data.List> putStrLn $ unlines $ show <$> sortBy (comparing name) tuples
("B",101,"M",3,"Jon",3.33)
("B",273,"F",1,"Mike",2.66)
("B",203,"R",3,"Rachel",1.66)
("A",200,"P",1,"Rachel",0.0)
("A",999,"N",3,"Rachel",1.33)
("A",100,"Q",3,"Todd",2.0)
("A",549,"D",3,"Todd",2.0)
("B",220,"S",3,"Todd",4.0)
```

Compared to the OP, this is in the opposite order of what's required, but I'll leave it as an exercise to figure out how to change the sort order. There's a couple of different ways to do that.

Comment: Also consider `sortOn`.